# New tab bar has poor dark mode contrast for bountied counter in focused, non-hover state on questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the darkmode focused, non-pointer-over state of buttons in the new tab bar, specifically for the "Bountied" tab in the questions page, the counter has light blue background, and light grey text. It's hard to read due to poor contrast. I assume this is unintentional.

[image]

I can repro on SO, but not on MSE.

Also, this happens in the `/questions` page, but not the home page. The home page tab bar looks like this:

[image]

Aside: The blue outline with grey focus background looks kind of bad, and seems inconsistent with the rest of the design.

(Note: I have a userstyle that makes the background darker, but I can repro the issue even with it turned off)

Comment: It is terrible, the whole bar is useless in portrait mode. Can barely get 5 letters in the search bar on SO in landscape, iPhone 14.

Comment: @zcoop98 but you're missing tab focus. you have hover state but not focus state. I'm talking about focus state with no hover state.

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would probably help explain the issue.

Comment: We've just released a change to our button group and the badges within them. I've let the team know there's a contrast issue here that snuck in. We should have a fix soon. The grey background color is to match the muted style of the button. We follow this pattern so that we can maintain a visual difference between muted (grey), default (blue) and danger (red) style buttons when in focus.